# Flash player malfunction after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, upgrade, flash

I am missing or have a problem with flash player after upgrade from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. this is reported after i try to play a you tube aplication

Comment: reinstall it from software center

Comment: On which browser does the problem lie? In case it is Chrome, install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`.